# How to use Bootstrap collapse in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am new to Angular and I have two collapse div elements and when I click on button1 then div element-1 need to collapse and element-2 need to be hide.

And when I click button2 then div element-2 need to collapse and element-1 need to be hide, but it's not working using below code.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="selectItem='one'" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">Simple
    collapsible</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="selectItem='two'" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">Simple
    collapsible</button>

  <div [ngClass]="(selectItem=='one')?'visiable':'hide'">
    <div id="demo1" class="collapse">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div [ngClass]="(selectItem=='two')?'visiable':'hide'">
    <div id="demo2" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-bootstrap4-crud-device-list-simple-zxunj1?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a look on this library:
[ng bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

I couldnt managed to make collapse work without this
The advantage is no additional javascript required

Answer (score 0):

You should toggle the `show` class on the `collapse` divs...

```
  <div>
    <div id="demo1" class="collapse" [ngClass]="{'show':selectItem=='one'}">
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div id="demo2" class="collapse" [ngClass]="{'show':selectItem=='two'}">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-bootstrap4-crud-device-list-simple-wwbgwd?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: is there is no animation? when collapse views like https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1L0YS28W4M9